# Why aren't my templates rendering

Tags: ember.js, transition

I've created some random views with the latest transition stuff from ember and the outlets aren't rendering. It's saying it's transitioning, but nothings showing up in the output window. (Note this works if I completely remove the routes)

Here it is:

> [jsfiddle to example](http://jsfiddle.net/GMVxM/)

```
App.PageRoute = Em.Router.extend({
    model: function(params, transition){
        return App.Page.find(params.page_id);
    }
});
```

Does it have to do with promises?  Am I supposed to be returning a promise instead of the actual model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `route` is extending the `Router`! It should be,

```
App.PageRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params, transition){
        return App.Page.find(params.page_id);
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtzqv/).

Comment: sob, thanks, wow, I can't believe I missed that... It's too late.