# Ember data Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to use ember data to get json data from my rails backend. Here's the app.js

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    console.log(this._super(record, suffix) +'.json');
    return this._super(record, suffix) + '.json';
  }
});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('post', params.post_id);
  }
});
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }
});

App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  updated_at: DS.attr('date')
});
```

and here's the data being returned by /posts.json

```
{
  "posts":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Some Title",
      "body": "Some text",
      "created_at": "2014-05-04T22:25:35.578Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-05-04T22:25:35.578Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Some Title",
      "body": "Some text",
      "created_at": "2014-05-04T22:25:35.578Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-05-04T22:25:35.578Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

The this.store.find('post') seems to not be working, but I'm not sure why. After looking through docs and a few tutorials I don't see the problem with the code. here's the error I'm getting.

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Ember.Object.extend.applyTransforms (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.min.js:9:15567)
    at Ember.Object.extend.normalize (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.min.js:9:15707)
    at superFunction [as _super] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-1.5.1.js:7724:16)
    at d.extend.normalize (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.min.js:9:18220)
    at superWrapper [as normalize] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-1.5.1.js:1293:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.min.js:9:19505)
    at Array.map (native)
    at d.extend.extractArray (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.min.js:9:19474)
    at superWrapper (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-1.5.1.js:1293:16)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extractFindAll (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.min.js:9:16821)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're model is extending the wrong object, I don't see any other obvious errors.

#### Incorrect

```
App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  updated_at: DS.attr('date')
});
```

#### Correct

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  created_at: DS.attr('date'),
  updated_at: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Works great now. Thanks so much!

Comment: All good, I had an awesome foo moment like that, extending Router instead of Route, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607675/why-arent-my-templates-rendering